# Symfony2 bundle on multiple corporate websites best practices

Tags: symfony, bundle, vendor

I'm working on a project ... creating a bundle which is gonna be use in multiple instances of sf2. And I wonder what is the best practice about it ?
Let it go in src/ or in vendor/ and have it on our git server ?
I've tried without success to create one in vendor but I always have error like it cannot be registered.

What is the best practice about that ? and if it's vendor dir ... do you know anyplace where I can find guidelines about setting it up properly?

Comment: do you have symfony 2.0 or 2.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice answer is to use 'composer.json', '/vendors' and the symfony documentation to create a working bundle stored in version control. Based on what you said, it seems like you're very close. Then override the bundle via '/src' for minor bundle tweaks on each of the multiple apps which run the bundle. This will keep everything clean and manageable.

Comment: thanks it's kinda what I expected but wasn't sure it was the "best" practice.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should check this http://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md  . You dont need to publish it at composer packagist. As far as i know you can put tha bundle within src in case you need to be easily modified with whole project. If you want more control then you just need the right rules in composer in order to put it at /vendor for anyone who want to use it.

Comment: So if I understand well ... I still can develop it in /src and I wanna use it in other websites I'll juste have to configure the composer.json file, right ?